# Shell unselected tab bar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to have a shell tab bar with all options unselected.
The default behaviour is to have the first option selected.
An alternative is to have a dummy option and hide it but even this is no possible.

Comment: It seems like can not do that in Shell App.

Comment: Unfortunately. The only this, I could do is to have a first dummy option (disabled), without text and icon, however I also don't see a width property, so this dummy option always take a huge space.

Comment: I am curious why need all options unselected .If realize this will not know which view of Tabs is shown ,or you want to show a  other page view when first enter shell App .

Comment: My client requested that. He don't want to "force the user to a choice". The unselected option will have a empty screen with the logo on the center. I'm thinking in a first "Begin" option with the property "IsEnabled = false" with that starting page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is:
1. Create a first Tab (I called Home).
2. This first tab shows a Page with a background image, a logo on the center and a Label on the footer with the following message: "Please select an option".

It's not the ideal solution but it was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately** , this should can not be realzied in current version of Shell . It should be the limit of Shell .

**[Tab class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-class)** :The `Tab` class includes the following properties that control tab appearance and behavior:

...

- **IsChecked**
  , of type boolean, defines if the item is currently highlighted in the flyout.

...

However this is a read-only property .And there is no other propery can be setted by not showing unselceted status .If want to realzie it , maybe you can have a try with [Shell Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers) .

Comment: Thank you. I'm already tried everything, check the documentation for all the supported properties. The unselected option will have a empty screen with the logo on the center. I'm thinking in a first "Begin" option with the property "IsEnabled = false" with that starting page.

Comment: @Hugo Okey , if find workaround , you can share it in answer .